# Meaning of "veteran" as a noun for a person in British English

Tags: meaning, british-english

In British English, if "veteran" is used as a noun to refer to a person, without saying what they are a veteran of, does it default to mean veteran in the sense of military service?

Comment: Please show evidence of research. [CD](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/veteran) indicates that the standalone usage is largely found outside the UK. 'A veteran of ...' is far more normal in the UK.

Comment: It’s context dependent.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Or "a veteran ..."

Answer (score 1):

The primary meaning of 'veteran' seems to be a soldier, sailor, etc. in a war, but as it comes from Latin veteranus and vetus 'old' might be modified by 'of ...' or Saxon Genetiv.
So we may find 'a veteran' as a person who served in Armed Forces for a period of time or in specific formation/conflict (Navy veteran, WWII veteran, veteran of Afghan War, etc.), but at the same time it may denote a person who participated in some activity for a long period of time (beauty contests' veteran, car races' veteran, etc.)

Comment: All this is true, but the OP was asking about British English, in which, as Edwin says, it is less common to use _veteran_ on its own to mean an ex-serviceman/woman. I think, if someone was described as a veteran, the response would be "Of what?"

Comment: Also, 'answers' on ELU need fairly thorough evidence backing claims.